Is there a macOS equivalent to Linux/Unix `/etc/login.defs?`
Is there a macOS equivalent to /etc/login.defs in Linux/Unix?
I was trying to find a safe range of group ID numbers to use when creating groups, and an answer on Unix SE had a useful answer referencing /etc/login.defs. However, googling "macos" "GID_MIN" "GID_MAX" had no obvious results.

By coincidence, this was posted in the last day or two: https://usercomp.com/news/1330029/macos-equivalent-to-etc-login-defs-for-safer-group-ids   That may help.

@Gilby You should post an answer with "No, but..." and then include that useful source you mentioned.

I now have serious doubts about that source. Nevertheless, I have added an answer with pointers as to how you might proceed.

macOS does not use etc/login.defs.
At first sight /etc/passwd and /etc/group are related as is suggested by macOS Equivalent to /etc/login.defs for Safer Range Group ID Numbers. But this is not correct - on macOS they only contain lists of users and groups used in a bare bones macOS and, according to the file headers, are only used when running in single user mode.
In spite of the article linked above talking about setting GIDMax and GIDMin as a way of setting a safe range for groups, the suggested commands do not work and, I believe, those parameters are not used in macOS. (I am open to being corrected on this).
The group and user database can be inspected and modified in these ways.

dscl is the macOS command to read and modify users and groups in the local accounts database.  It is described in its man page. I recommend not using this, except for reading data, without expert guidance. Regarding groups commands like dscl . -list /Groups and dscl . -read /Groups/xxx safely provide information.

The Directory Utility /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app is a GUI app which can be used to explore (and potentially change) the local accounts directory /Local/Default. Note that its help only addresses using the utility for LDAP and Active Directory.

For just listing and reading from the local accounts database, the open source command line app osquery provides a SQL like interface to many system parameters.  For the local accounts database Terminal commands like: osqueryi "select gid, groupname from groups order by gid;" can be useful.


There are numerous questions in superuser and Ask Different referring to dscl usage.
